# iphone simulators and devices are not listed at 'Base SDKs' on Xcode 'edit project settings'

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, ios4, ios-simulator

I installed 'xcode_3.2.5_and_ios_sdk_4.2_final.dmg'.

When i build a project, xcode say below

"error: There is no SDK with the name or path 'iphoneos3.2'"

So, I checked this site, and i find out like that you should select 'iphone simulator 4.x' to 'Base SDKs' on Xcode 'edit project settings'.

But, I can not select iphone simulator 4.x.

There are no 'Iphone Simulator x.x' in Base SDKs list as below. also there are no 'Iphone Device x.x' too.

**Base SDKs selections**

---

Current Mac OS

Mac OS X SDKs

∟　Mac OS X 10.5

∟　Mac OS X 10.6

∟　Latest Mac OS X (Currently set to Mac OS X 10.6

iOS SDKs

∟　iOS 4.2

∟　Latest iOS (Currently set to iOS 4.2)

other..

---

※I want to upload image capture, But new user is not allowed.

How Can i select 'Iphone Simulator x.x'?

Please Help!

Answer (score 3):

Right click your project's root title, select "Get info"

Inside the menu you make sure you select this: Base SDK -> Lastest(iOS 4.2....)

Besides, do the same process to your *Target* file. See my third screenshot.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks you for your quickly answer!! 
I tried it, But build get error as below
"error: There is no SDK with the name or path 'iphoneos3.2'" yet.
Also  i restarted xcode too..

Comment: +1 :( I have option to give you only one upvote ... you solved my problem your third screenshot did the right thing ....

Answer (score 2):

Please, do what diwup says, then:

- Open your project file (the one that has the .xcodeproj extension) with a text editor and find the line where the old version is written:
  [image]
- Delete the line SDKROOT = iphoneos3.2;
- Re-open your project.

That's what I just did.

Comment: Thanks iPhoneDevProf.
I do what you say, and I can works! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Right click your project's root title, select "Get info"

Inside build menu  Plz set ios deployemnt  target to ios 3.2..

Answer (score 0):

You can just select "Latest iOS (Currently set to iOS 4.2)", for most projects it is the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select "Latest iOS" in the "Base SDK" build setting popup and "iOS 3.2" in the "iOS Deployment Target" build setting popup. Now you can select an older iOS Simulator in the "Overview" popup in the top left corner of the project window.

You should set both of these in the project build settings and clear any selection in the target build settings (select each in the build settings window and press the Delete key), unless there is some specific reason you need custom settings for different targets in your project.

(You can also choose older version in iOS Simulator itself, via the "Hardware" menu.)